# Is there a way to render an engine's 'super' view within the main app's overridden view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I am developing an engine with a controller and views, but I want to allow for the views to be overridden (this is simple enough as Rails::Engine allows for this by automatically prepending `app/views` from the main app to the view path for the engine). However, I want the overridden view to be able to refer to the view from the engine - for example, I want to "wrap" the engine's view with custom stuff in my app:

```
# main_app/app/views/engine/template.haml

# ... custom stuff here
= render template: 'engine/template'
# ... custom stuff here
```

The problem is, I can't find a way to refer to the engine's view once I override it... is it possible?

Comment: Would `render template: "#{YourEngine::Engine.root}/engine/template"` work? it can be wrapped in a helper to like `super_view` that returns the view file path for the engine.

Comment: @tihom doesn't seem to work, gives me: `Missing template /path/to/engine/engine/template`

Comment: it needs to be `render file: ...` and the file path modified so it represents the full path of the template file like may be need to add `app/views`

Comment: OK, that actually works (one I added `app/views` into the path as well). Not particularly friendly, but a start. You should add it as an answer instead of comment.

Comment: modified a bit to use filename by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rendering the file by providing the full path of the engine's template file.

```
  # in view
  <%= engine_view {|f| render file: f} %>

  # in helper
  def engine_view(&b)
     yield eval("__FILE__.gsub(Rails.root.to_s, YourEngine::Engine.root.to_s)",b.binding) 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

tihom's approach is good, but the block feels unnecessarily hacky (and rubocop won't like it). I prefer something like:

```rb
## in helper
def render_engine_view
  render file: caller_locations.first.path.gsub(Rails.root.to_s, YourEngine::Engine.root.to_s)
end

## in view
# ... custom stuff here
<%= render_engine_view %>
# ... custom stuff here
```